# opam install error "no solution found"

Tags: ocaml, opam

I came across a bug when installing certain packages using opam.

```
> opam install foo
Sorry, no solution found: there seems to be a problem with your request.

No solution found, exiting
```

Comment: Just as a side-note, make sure you have an external dependency solver installed (such as `aspcud`). OPAM's internal solver is known to be a little unstable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to particular form of the error message I read you are using the opam v1.2 internal solver (which you can confirm via `opam config report`). This solver is no longer able to cope with the repository.

Either install an external solver, see [here](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html#External-Solvers) or switch to `opam v2` (currently in rc) which bundles a decent solver.

Comment: FWIW, I just got this from opam 2.0.3 when trying to install httpaf-async or httpaf-lwt-unix.

Answer (score 3):

Opam was using a version of the ocaml compiler that wasn't able to install this package. So unistall the current version and use `opam switch` to set opam to use the latest ocaml compiler.

```
> opam switch x.xx.x
```

Then make sure to update/upgrade opam.

```
> opam update
> opam upgrade
```

Comment: You might want to do `opam update` before creating the switch.

Comment: Hmm... in 2021-12, looks like maybe this should be `opam switch create x.xx.x` ? I would edit the answer, but I don't have enough experience using opam to be confident here.